# Cisco routing between two VRF

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, vrf

I have this scenario where i have two 10G link from my `ISP` and both link has two class C `/24` public IP which is mentioned in diagram. I want to router data between two VRF `RED` & `BLUE`

[image]

How do i router data between two VRF `RED` & `BLUE`?

## EDIT

If there any other way we can achieve this scenario without using VRF?

Comment: If you want to route between them, why did you configure them as separate VRFs? Also, if the two switches are layer-3 switches, why not route, instead of trunk, between them? The current best practice is to extend layer-3 as low as possible, even to the access switch.

Comment: By the way, those addresses are not Class C addresses, and network classes were deprecated in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519. Modern networking doesn't use network classes. Network classes were determined by the bit number of the first `0` bit in the address.

Comment: I totally understand `VLSM` addressing i just wanted to say its `/24` subnet, it was my mistake i said Class `C` (default Class C is /24) anyway,  Both link coming from my ISP with different handoff IPs and associated public IPs, now i have L3 switch so i need to define `Default GW` for both handoff and that is only possible in `VRF`  am i missing something here?

Comment: "_now i have L3 switch so i need to define Default GW for both handoff and that is only possible in VRF am i missing something here?_" A layer-3 switch has a routing module, so you do not need to define a default gateway. That would be for a layer-2 switch. With a layer-3 switch, just like with a router, you use the routing table to define where to send traffic.

Comment: Normally, you use VRFs to separate traffic where you do not want the traffic to be able to be routed between, but you do want that, so I think you may be looking at this incorrectly.

Comment: perhaps this will assist ? http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/mar/29/inter-vrf-routing-vrf-lite/

Comment: @RonMaupin reason i need traffic router netween `70.x` and `64.x` net because we have some shared service which require communication between both and i don't want that traffic will go all the way up to ISP router and come back, I was thinking we both are on same switch then why not just router them.  If you have this kind of scenario how would you handle this? what you will do to make it simple and possible?

Comment: no one knows any alternative if i don't want to use `VRF`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few options for you to route the traffic between VRFs. Below are two of them:

- The first option is to use MP-BGP (Multiprotocol BGP) with RD (Route
  Distinguisher) and RTs (Route Targets).
- The second option is to use static routes and make use the global (default) routing table. I wrote a blog post about this option on my blog [Netlabbuilder](http://netlabbuilder.net/cisco-ios-inter-vrf-routing-with-static-route-and-next-hop/).

There is a nice post about these two options from [Routing-Bits](https://routing-bits.com/2010/09/13/vrf-lite-route-leaking/).

However, I would suggest you not to do that if you do not clearly understand how it works and what you want to achieve. This would result in issues while you set it up and troubleshoot them later.

Comment: very neat example!!